# How to make C# WPF ContentControl Serializable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to Serialize a list of ContentControl which contains an image and a textbox so I can save them into a binary file.

The error message

> Type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable."

Comment: Obi-Wan says: "That is not the way you are looking for."

Comment: I see...What is the best way of saving these contentcontrol objects then?

Comment: Do not try to save content controls at all. Their main purpose is to interact with the user

Comment: What is the interesting part of the textbox you want to save? Position, FontSize, Height, ... or maybe the Text (which is the content)?

Comment: So these contentcontrol were rotated by user, text were altered by user.  I thought it might be easier to just save the whole contentcontrol rather than get each of the properties out and save them.  But if making contentcontrol serializable is too much of trouble I may have to do that...

Comment: Build a class that can hold all necessary data and write some code to save/load it. Then you can bind the data to the controls. Read some tutorials about MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't serialise a control as they are view states

if you are following MVVM then your controls should be displaying a View Model, and that View Model will be manipulating a Model, and the Model is the thing that you should serialise

here is an example

XAML

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel x:Name="vm" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Collection}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="New Item">
            <StackPanel>
                <GroupBox Header="Text">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewText}"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox >
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        <Button Command="{Binding Browse, Mode=OneWay}">Uri</Button>
                    </GroupBox.Header>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewUri}"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <Button Command="{Binding Add, Mode=OneWay}" >Add</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvs}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Text}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Uri}" Stretch="None"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding Delete, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding /, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvs}}" >Delete</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Cancel, Mode=OneWay}" >Cancel</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Save, Mode=OneWay}" >Save</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Load, Mode=OneWay}" >Load</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Models

```
[Serializable]
public class ImageModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
}

public class ImageCollectionModel
{
    public List<ImageModel> Collection { get; } = new List<ImageModel>();

    private BinaryFormatter Formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    public bool Save(FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenWrite())
            {
                Formatter.Serialize(stream, Collection);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool Load(FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
            {
                var col = Formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<ImageModel>;
                Collection.Clear();
                Collection.AddRange(col);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel:BindableBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Add = new DelegateCommand(() => Collection.Add(new ImageModel()
        {
            Text = NewText,
            Uri = new Uri(NewUri)
        }));
        Delete = new DelegateCommand<ImageModel>(item => Collection.Remove(item));
        Load = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            var open = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            if (open.ShowDialog() ?? false)
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    if (Model == null)
                    {
                        Model = new ImageCollectionModel();
                    }
                    Model.Load(file);
                }
                Cancel.Execute();
            }

        });
        Save = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            var save = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            if (save.ShowDialog() ?? false)
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(save.FileName);
                if (!file.Exists)
                {
                    if (Model == null)
                    {
                        Model = new ImageCollectionModel();
                    }
                    Model.Collection.Clear();
                    Model.Collection.AddRange(Collection);
                    Model.Save(file);
                }
            }
        });
        Cancel = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            Collection.Clear();
            if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Collection)
                {
                    Collection.Add(item);
                }
            }
        });
        Browse = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            var open = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            if (open.ShowDialog() ?? false)
            {
                NewUri = open.FileName;
            }
        });
    }
    public ImageCollectionModel Model { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> Collection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();

    private string _NewText;

    public string NewText
    {
        get { return _NewText; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _NewText, value); }
    }

    private string _NewUri;

    public string NewUri
    {
        get { return _NewUri; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _NewUri, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand Add { get;  }
    public DelegateCommand<ImageModel> Delete { get;  }
    public DelegateCommand Browse { get; }
    public DelegateCommand Load { get; }
    public DelegateCommand Save { get; }
    public DelegateCommand Cancel { get; }

}
```

**NOTE: this example makes use of PRISM and c# 6.0**